# If null space and the range of a linear mapping is finite dimensional then the departure space is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, alternative-proof

There are several questions posted which are looking for solutions and hints. I was hoping that someone could **verify** my proof.

---

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and $A:V\to W$ be a linear mapping. Suppose that $\dim \ker A = s$ and $\dim A(V) = t$. We need to show that $A$ is finite dimensional.

We assume the contrary that $V$ is not finite dimensional, hence we can find an infinite list of linearly independent vectors.

We have been given that $\dim \ker A = s$, thus, we can find a basis $\{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s \}$ for $\ker A$. Now, *here's my proof strategy*: I will extend the previous list to $\{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1}, \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$ such that $\{ A(\alpha_{s+1}) , \ldots , A(\alpha_{s+t}) \}$ is a basis for $A(V)$ and this list $\{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$ is linearly independent.

Let $\alpha_{s+1} \in V\setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s \}$ be arbitrary. 
Now, we can pick $\alpha_{s+2} \in V\setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1} \}$ such that $A(\alpha_{s+2}) \not\in \text{Sp} \{ A(\alpha_{s+1})\}$. For otherwise we would have that for all $\alpha_{s+2} \in V\setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1} \}$, $A(\alpha_{s+2}) \in \text{Sp} \{ A(\alpha_{s+1})\}$ which implies that $A(V)= \text{Sp} \{ A(\alpha_{s+1})\}$ and which further would contradict our assumption that $\dim A(V) = t$. Again, we can pick $\alpha_{s+3} \in V\setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1}, \alpha_{s+2} \}$ such that $A(\alpha_{s+2}) \not\in \text{Sp} \{ A(\alpha_{s+1}) ,A(\alpha_{s+2})\}$ (The argument for it is same as the previous one!). If we repeat this argument for $t$ times, we would have found vectors such that $\{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1}, \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$ such that the vectors $\{ A(\alpha_{s+1}) , \ldots , A(\alpha_{s+t}) \}$ are linear independent and this list $\{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$ is linearly independent. Since, we know that linearly independent vectors of right length is the basis, it must be that $\{ A(\alpha_{s+1}) , \ldots , A(\alpha_{s+t}) \}$ form a basis for $A(V)$.

Now, we bring about a contradiction. Pick a vector $v \in V \setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1}, \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$. $A(v) \in A(V)$, thus, $A(v)=c_1 A(\alpha_{s+1}) + \ldots + c_t A(\alpha_{s+t})$. By definition of linear mappings, we have $A(v-c_1
\alpha_{s+1}- \ldots - c_t \alpha_{s+t})=0$. It follows that $v-c_1
\alpha_{s+1}- \ldots - c_t \alpha_{s+t} \in \ker A$ thus $v-c_1
\alpha_{s+1}- \ldots - c_t \alpha_{s+t}=d_1 \alpha_1 + \ldots + d_s \alpha_s$ which is contradicts our assumption that $v \not \in \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_s , \alpha_{s+1}, \ldots , \alpha_{s+t} \}$. Thus, $V$ must be finite dimensional.

---

Is this proof correct? I know it's a long proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes -- you have the right idea. The sentence "We assume the contrary that V is not finite dimensional, hence we can find an infinite list of linearly independent vectors." isn't really doing anything. You could leave it out, and just turn the contradiction at the end into showing that $V$ is finite-dimensional, which you did anyway.

Comment: @csprun isn't it implicit in that fact the $V$ minus span of vectors is nonempty? For otherwise V could be the span of some vectors and I couldn't find anymore vectors I did in the proof?

Comment: You mean at the very end? Instead of picking $v$ outside that span, just pick any $v \in V$ and show it's in that span. You hardly have to change anything in your proof.

Comment: @csprun oh yes that's right. There's no need of contradiction anyways. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure! Good luck.